# Display image on a JLabel from a blob column in Oracle database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, swing

How to display image on a JLabel from a blob column in oracle database?

Hello I have been struggling for days now trying
 to figure out how I can display an image on a jLabel
 from a blob column in oracle database but all efforts
 seems not sufficient to produce desired results.
 The problem is that the Label displays a dark
 colour stuff like background. I've spent so much time 
googling and also searching here on the stack overflow
 but, the available resources aren't putting me through
 Please help me out !. 
thanks. Below is the code segment I'm working with .....

```
    private void studentIdItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt)          {                                           
        String id = (String)studentId.getSelectedItem();


        try{


             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test", "SYSTEM", "VICTOR");
             stmt = con.createStatement();
             result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from STUDENTDBASE.STUDENT where   Student_Id = '" + id + "' ");
             result = stmt.getResultSet();

             while (result.next()){
                 surname.setText(result.getString("Surname"));
                 firstName.setText(result.getString("First_Name"));
                 otherNames.setText(result.getString("Other_Names"));
                 phoneNumber.setText(result.getString("Mobile_Number"));
                 dob.setText(result.getString("Date_Of_Birth"));
                 gender.setText(result.getString("Gender"));
                 address.setText(result.getString("Address"));
                 state.setText(result.getString("State"));
                 lga.setText(result.getString("Lga"));

                }
             result.close();


             PreparedStatement ps;           
             con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test", "SYSTEM", "VICTOR");
             ps = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("select Image from STUDENTDBASE.STUDENT_Images where STUDENT_ID = '" + id + "' ");
             result2 = ps.executeQuery();

             while (result2.next()){


                InputStream in = result2.getBinaryStream("Image");


               BufferedImage im = ImageIO.read(in); 
               BufferedImage outimage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
               Graphics2D g = outimage.createGraphics();

                float xScale = (float)image.getWidth() / outimage.getWidth();
                float yScale = (float)image.getHeight() / outimage.getHeight();
                AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(xScale,yScale);
                g.drawRenderedImage(im,at);
                g.dispose();
                Image scaledImage = outimage.getScaledInstance(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
                image.setIcon(icon);
                image.revalidate();
                basicDetails.revalidate();
                }
             result2.close();
             con.close();
   }
   catch(SQLException d){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error is due to " + d.getMessage(), "Error message from database", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   }
       catch(IOException io){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error is due to " + io.getMessage(), "Error message from database", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }







//Insert Student image into database
            url = "jdbc:odbc:test";
            String query1 = "insert into STUDENTDBASE.STUDENT_Images (Student_Id, Image, Image_Path, Image_Size)values('" + counterValue + "', ?, '" + path + "', '" + stringLength + "' ) ";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "SYSTEM", "VICTOR");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(query1);
            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream(file);
            ps.setString(1, file.getName());
            ps.setBinaryStream(2, fin, file.length());
            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The image never got inserted because you are using `PreparedStatement` incorrectly. You have to use ? for all the parameters, not just one of them.

Comment: @JB I just effected the suggestions buh ! O my God ! This code doesn't wanna work. There is no visible difference from the previous code. Could you just graciously run this from ur end for me pls. i'm so confused but will never give up !